# matplotlib.pyplot.hist returns a histogram where all bins have the same value when I have varying data

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram in python using matplotlib.pyplot.hist.
I have an array of data that varies, however when put my code into python the histogram is returned with values in all bins equal to each other, or equal to zero which is not correct.

The histogram should look the the line graph above it with bins roughly the same height and in the same shape as the graph above.

The line graph above the histogram is there to illustrate what my data looks like and to show that my data does vary.

My data array is called spectrumnoise and is just a function I have created against an array x

```
x=np.arange[0.1,20.1,0.1]
```

The code I am using to create the histogram and the line graph above it is

```
import matplotlib.pylot as mpl 
mpl.plot(x,spectrumnoise)
mpl.hist(spectrumnoise,bins=50,histtype='step')
mpl.show()
```

I have also tried using

```
mpl.hist((x,spectrumnoise),bins=50,histtype=step)
```

I have also changed the number of bins countless times to see if that helps an normalising the histogram function but nothing works.

Image of the output of the code can be seen here 
[image]

Comment: The graph does vary (ie not all in one bin and has different values in bins), what should it look like

Comment: The histogram should look like the line graph above, the data in the line graph in the same as that being used for the histogram, yet my histogram function is not working
So the histogram bars should be roughly as high as the line graph above it

Comment: Your questions says "However the only output I get is the picture below, even though my data obviously varies. " and the data does vary in the output

Comment: Yes I know it does, but I need to produce a histogram of my data, I don't want a line graph.

Comment: The line graph is there purely to show what the histogram should look like, what I need is help on why my histogram is showing that I have data that doesn't vary when I obviously do

Comment: Can you edit to say that then please, the question says that the graph is the plot of your data that you are getting and can you show what you are getting

Comment: I have shown what I'm getting. The graph is correct, the histogram beneath the graph shown in many different colors is not, it should match the graph above it, as is apparent in the code

Comment: @LiziSwann : I'm pretty sure the issue comes from the number of bins. 50 is way too much for this kind of data. Try 5 or 6 and tell us if it's better. ( Or show us your spectrumnoise data )

Comment: @georgesl As I said in the comments I have tried with a number of bins ranging from 4 to 100. I can put up the spectrum noise data but it is about 30 lines of code as it is a function of x with three separate Gaussian functions imposed on top of it using slicing and is not very relevant to my problem (I have been trying with other sets of data to create histograms and other simpler data sets are not working either).  Just fyi, when using 5 bins my histogram looks like this http://i40.tinypic.com/2n1chvs.png

Comment: @georgesl, also, as you can see even though I have used 5 bins loads more seem to have appeared even though I am using mpl.hist(spectrumnoise,bins=5)

Comment: Are you sure that hist is the correct function? It seems that the data in `spectrumnoise` is already binned, rather than the raw samples. If that is the case, you could just draw a bar chart (e.g., `mpl.bar(x, spectrumnoise, width=0.25)`)

Comment: @Bonlenfum I will try using a bar chart but my data is not binned. My full code can be seen here http://i40.tinypic.com/atlp29.png. I need to produce a histogram though, I doing research which requires a histogram and neither me nor my lecturer can figure out why this isnt working

Comment: @LiziSwann could you post the code as text rather than an image? (e.g. on http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Bonlenfum Just tried using a bar chart. My data is definitely not binned I got a bar chart which had as many bars as I had data points. However if someone can tell me how to bin my data without using a histogram this would also help. I have only been using python for 2 days so I kind of need basic explanations as to how to do things because I have only started to learn programming. Thanks

Comment: @Bonlenfum
http://pastebin.com/ChVh9iNq
Thanks for all your help

Comment: Ah, looking directly at how you generated the data reveals you've got a bit of a mixture of types.  `mpl.hist` expects an array-like set of data, but your `spectrumnoise` is a list, each element of which is an numpy array of length 1.  I think a quick fix is to put it into a numpy array (`spectrumnoise = np.array(spectrum[:])` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `spectrumnoise` is a `list` of arrays, not a `numpy.ndarray`. When you hand `hist` a list of arrays as its first argument, it treats each element as a *separate* dataset to plot. All the bins have the same height because each 'dataset' in the list has only one value in it!

From the `hist` docstring:

> Multiple data can be provided via *x* as a list of datasets
>   of potentially different length ([*x0*, *x1*, ...]), or as
>   a 2-D ndarray in which each column is a dataset.

Try converting `spectrumnoise` to a 1D array:

```
pp.hist(np.vstack(spectrumnoise),50)
```

As an aside, looking at your code there's absolutely no reason to convert your data to lists in the first place. What you ought to do is operate directly on slices in your array, e.g.:

```
data[20:40] += y1
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had no idea why it wasn't working, I'm glad it's something so simple. And I converted all the data to lists because I had no idea how to add arrays together, so thankyou very much for helping me simplify my code!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. For future reference, if you ever do need to concatenate arrays together you can use `np.concatenate` (although concatenating arrays is slow and generally best avoided).